# Enumerate USB flash drives programatically using libudev in Linux

Tags: c, linux, usb, udev

How can I programmatically enumerate all the USB flash drives using libudev under Linux? I want to get the strings such as '`/dev/sdb4`' so that I can then use '`mount()`' to mount them.

I was following the libudev example at http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/. The example code works well for '`hidraw`'; I then tried '`usb`', '`scsi_disk`', '`scsi_generic`', etc, but didn't work - it didn't list the 'device path' like '`/dev/sdb4`', it said '`Device Node Path: (null)`'.

Comment: I don't know the answer. I just want to say I like the word "enumulate", that's all.

Comment: @Wang Tuma I am also woring on similar thing. I have the same issue. I used "block", and it list all the drives.. I want only usb Flash drives... Is there a way to get already connected usb flash drive ?? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361042/how-to-list-usb-mass-storage-devices-programatically-using-libudev-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `scsi_generic` search for the `block` sub-node. There you should find the block device.

`scsi_generic` is a different interface.

I'll add a bit of explanation, but note that I'm no expert in the subject, just an observer...

SCSI devices are quite complex and have different several interfaces to access different feature sets.

The `scsi_generic` device is a *character* device (usually named `/dev/sg<n>`) that gives access to SCSI features. For example, CD/DVD recorders are (were?) usually managed through this device. But access to the blocks of data is used through the standard block devices, so each SCSI device that looks like a disk (remember, there are also SCSI printers...) will create also a block sub-node.

But a USB flash drive is not a real SCSI device, it just uses the same protocol, quite simplified. So, to avoid rewriting the same protocol for USB, the kernel creates a virtual SCSI device and connects it to the USB device.

The thing with this virtual SCSI devices is that they have the minimum necessary to present themselves as a block device. So the lack many of the SCSI specific features, particularly the `scsi_generic` interface. That's why you get a `(null)` there. Not that it could be useful to you, as you cannot mount a `scsi_generic` device, as it is not a block device at all!.

Comment: Yes 'block' works! but why? I actually thought 'scsi_disk' is the right sub-node. Will you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: @WangTuma: Sure! I've added a bit of explanation.